# Including a list of manually selected online newspaper articles (Flutter)

Tags: flutter

I am an absolute beginner in programming and I have set myself the goal of creating an app for our small association.

I would also like to create a kind of news feed on a page in which I can post local newspaper articles
can add manually. So selected articles. I know that it is probably very complex at the beginning, but I want to get an idea of ​​how and what I need for it.

My question is, what hardware or software items do I need? Or how can that be done?
For now, I don't need any codes, I just need an overview of the means by which I can get there. And then I try to get used to it bit by bit.

Comment: Do you at least know the difference between Bakend and Frontend programming ?

Comment: Englisch

I can tell the difference. I have no experience with backend and I'm just starting out with frontend.

Without stiffening the topic, are there ready-made backend solutions that can be integrated into Flutter?

Comment: Maybe! But consider learning basics first

Comment: OK. what basics do you mean exactly and where should i start?

thank you in advance for replying :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thank you for your question.  Unfortunately the "what hardware or software items do I need" is too open-ended and goes against Stack Overflow's rule against questions which require "opinion based" answers.  Also, Stack Overflow questions should typically be about "specific coding, algorithm, or language problems."  I would recommend you check out [r/learnprogramming on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/61oly8/new_read_me_first/). However, please be sure to read their FAQ before posting.  There's a lot of helpful info there.